# Which GTK+ Widget to chose for this requirement?

Tags: gtk

I have a requirement in which i need to display in formation in a table with 4 columns
with header to it.

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|Header 1         |Header 2         |Header 3         |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-+
|GtkLabel Info 1  | GtkLabel Info 1 | GTKImage Info 1 |S|
|GtkLabel Info 2  | GtkLabel Info 2 | GTKImage Info 2 |C|
|GtkLabel Info 3  | GtkLabel Info 3 | GTKImage Info 3 |R|
|GtkLabel Info 4  | GtkLabel Info 4 | GTKImage Info 4 |O|
|GtkLabel Info 5  | GtkLabel Info 5 | GTKImage Info 5 |L|
|GtkLabel Info 6  | GtkLabel Info 6 | GTKImage Info 6 |L|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-+
```

When user clicks (Right/Left) on any of the row i need to popup some menu.
so every row need to have some unique id or something like that so that i will get to know which contact has been selected. Plus i need to highlight selected row with some different color.

SO is there any widget in GTK that supports this functionality?

I tried with table but it is not giving me proper results as i want it.

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GTK TreeView

- [docs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeView.html)
- [images](http://images.google.ru/images?hl=ru&source=hp&q=gtktreeview&lr=&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=wi)

GTK TreeModel ([docs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1TreeModel.html)) allow store custom objects and GTK CellRenderer-s ([docs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1CellRenderer.html)) help you to display items using custom colors and fonts.

I don't know which language do you use, but there are the good tutorials for [Ruby](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?tut-treeview) and [Python](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html). [PyGtk FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=index) will help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am using GTK+ under C. can you provide some examples on this.